# SQL : How to Delete Rows; when defending “WHERE” from another table with Multiply Returns

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Query

```
    DELETE FROM TEMPSchedules 
           WHERE StudentID = ( Select StudentID 
                               From Students 
                               Where Ref = 'H1007')
```

### Error Message

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

### Problem

Now the problem is that each “Ref Group” has more than 1 Student attached to it. So how should I deal with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  DELETE FROM TEMPSchedules 
           WHERE StudentID  in ( Select distinct StudentID 
                               From Students 
                               Where Ref = 'H1007')
```

Comment: +1 for your query. But note that always describe your answer in detail. You should show how this query work etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE TEMPSchedules
From Students 
Where Students.Ref = 'H1007' and Students.StudentID=TEMPSchedules.StudentID
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statement selects only the DISTINCT values from the ""StudentID"" column in the ""Students"" table Where Ref = 'H1007':
`SELECT DISTINCT StudentID FROM Students;`